# Spring LDAP authenticate method with Pooling - UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, spring, authentication

I'm using Spring LDAP 2.0.0.RELEASE and am getting an error using the new ldapTemplate.authenticate(LdapQuery, password) method with ldap pooling turned on.  I get the error:

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported for this implementation

I only get this error when I have the ldap:pooling tag in my applicationContext.xml

When I remove this, the method works successfully.  Any idea why authenticate doesn't work with ldap pooling?  Pooling seems to work fine with other ldapTemplate methods.

Answer (score 2):

In order to authenticate the user the ContextSource performs a bind, which is accomplished by creating a new connection with the specified distinguished name and password. Due to this, these connections cannot be pooled.